# What do ncurses_def_shell_mode() and ncurses_def_prog_mode() do exactly?

Tags: php, ncurses, php-ncurses

Using [php ncurses](http://php.net/ncurses), I'm curious to understand exactly what `ncurses_def_shell_mode()` and `ncurses_def_prog_mode()` functions do specifically. They're not documented in the PHP manual and what little I did stumble upon in `man ncurses` didn't help.

If I call `ncurses_def_shell_mode()` and then reset with `ncurses_reset_shell_mode()` before calling `ncurses_end()`, which according to the extension's source should call `endwin` in ncurses, the terminal cursor is still somehow lost.

```
<?php
ncurses_init(); // start ncurses window
ncurses_def_shell_mode();

sleep(2); // print some stuff here

ncurses_reset_shell_mode();

ncurses_end(); // clean up and get out
exit;
?>
```

I tried with and without, `ncurses_def_shell_mode()` and `ncurses_def_prog_mode()`, but somehow the window is not reset properly on exit despite properly calling reset. Am I misunderstanding how these functions are supposed to work? I was able to dig up very little information to glean more insight into their proper usage.

I know that ncurses may be archaic, but that just makes it that much more difficult to know how to use it properly.

Expected behavior here is that after calling `ncurses_reset_shell_mode()` or `ncurses_reset_prog_mode()` the shell or prog window should go back to its previously saved state as it was before.

The actual behavior seems to be that the shell is an a broken state upon exiting. The cursor doesn't blink, typing does not reveal anything in the terminal. However, the terminal is receiving input properly, because typing in commands and hitting enter still works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[php ncurses](http://php.net/ncurses) is a wrapper around [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/).  The functions you are asking about are documented in more detail in the ncurses manual pages, e.g., [curs_kernel(3x)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_kernel.3x.html).  That says that these functions save/restore *terminal modes*.  Those correspond to curses settings in termios (terminal I/O settings).

Terminal I/O settings do not include blinking cursor (that is done using a terminal-specific escape sequence).  For echo, the [manual page](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_kernel.3x.html#h3-def_prog_mode_-def_shell_mode) can help:

> The  **`def_prog_mode`**  and  **`def_shell_mode`**  routines save the
>   current terminal modes as the  "program"  (in  curses)  or
>   "shell"   (not  in  curses)  state  for  use  by  the  **`reset_prog_mode`** and **`reset_shell_mode`** routines.  This is done
>   each screen context allocated by [newterm()](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-newterm).

When ncurses starts, e.g., [`initscr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-initscr) (`ncurses_init()`), it saves the shell-mode and initializes the prog-mode, basically putting the terminal into *raw* mode to better control it.

Your call to `ncurses_def_shell_mode();`

- saves the *prog-mode* **as** *shell-mode*, and
- when *"restoring"* to that using `ncurses_reset_shell_mode();`,
- it has no effect: the terminal remains in raw mode, with echo disabled.

Further reading:

- [PECL /[svn]/pecl/ncurses/trunk](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/ncurses/trunk/)
- [ncurses_functions](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/ncurses/trunk/ncurses_functions.c?revision=329488&view=markup), where `ncurses_init()` is defined.